# Ordinary and extraordinary polarization

Tags: terminology, polarization, non-linear-optics

The paper *Entangled biphoton source - property and preparation* says

> A very interesting situation of type-II SPDC is for ‘non-collinear phase matching’. The signal–idler pair are emitted from a SPDC crystal, for example BBO, cut in type-II phase matching, into two cones, one ordinary polarized, the other extraordinary polarized (see figure 10). Along the intersection, where the cones overlap, two pinholes numbered as 1 and 2 are used for defining the direction of the $k$ vectors of the signal–idler pair. One may consider the polarization state of the signal–idler pair as,
> $$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|o_1+e_2\rangle+|e_1o_2\rangle)$$
> where $o_j$, $e_j$, $j = 1, 2$ are ordinary and extraordinary polarization, respectively. 
> [image: Figure 10]

What does it mean by "ordinary and extraordinary polarization"? I haven't heard those terms before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of modeling light traveling through a medium is with ["ray-optics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics) which is a method by which you model your beam of light as a series of light rays. Here's a picture to give you an idea of what it looks like if you haven't seen it before:
[image]

One of the most basic principles of ray optics is Snell's Law, which tells you how each light-ray bends when they hit a medium. In the attached picture, ray-optics is used to show that light can be focused with a lens. The math of how this lens bends light can be derived from Snell's Law. Ray optics is a simplified model and there are exceptions; one particularly notable exception is birefringence, in which different polarizations of light get bent differently. Sometimes one of these polarizations obeys Snell's law (it acts *ordinary*) and the other one doesn't (it acts *extraordinary*). The main idea is simply that two beams travel two different paths along the crystal associated with the polarization.

I work in an quantum information lab that uses such a crystal for SPDC inside a cavity. Depending on what type of crystal you use, you can go from having entangled light to squeezed light!